# Laravel 5 getting ID from URL

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, pass-by-reference

I have a table view in which I can click an button icon and redirect to another page carrying the *id* of the row that has been clicked.

```
@foreach ($patients as $patient)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $patient->pID }}</td>
        <td>{{ $patient->pName }}</td> 
        <td>{{ $patient->pAddress }}</td>
        <td>{{ $patient->pBday }}</td>
        <td>{{ $patient->pPhone}}</td>
        <td>{{ $patient->pEcon }}</td>
        <td>{{ $patient->pDreg }}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ URL::to('visit/'.$patient->pID) }}">
                <img src="../images/viewvisit.png" style="width:30px; height:30px;">
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ URL::to('addeditvisit/'.$patient->pID) }}">
                <img src="../images/visit.png" style="width:30px; height:30px;">
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ URL::to('editpatient/'.$patient->pID) }}">
                <img src="../images/update.png" style="width:30px; height:30px;">
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ URL::to('deletepatient/'.$patient->pID) }}">
                <img src="../images/delete.png" style="width:30px; height:30px;">
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

what I want is to get the *id* from the URL and put it in a variable so that I can utilize it my other page.

I'm currently stuck with this controller function.

```
public function index(Request $request) {   

    $doctors = Doctor::where('dStatus', 0)
        ->lists('dName', 'dID');
    $beds = Bed::where('bStatus', 0)
        ->lists('bName', 'bID');
    $patient = Patient::patient();
    // $uri = $request->path('patient');

    return View::make('pages.addeditvisit', [
        'doctors'=>$doctors,
        'beds'=>$beds,
        'patient'=>$patient->pID
    ]);
}
```

Comment: How did you define your routes?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is late. But for the benefit of others like me;

If you do not have to do it in a method like the answers above have shown, As of Laravel 5.0 (Not sure about previous versions), you can do

```
$request->route('id');
```

That returns the value of the `id` parameter on the route.

Answer (score 32):

Or just use it within Blade: `{{ request()->route('id') }}`

Answer (score 24):

Basically when you are defining the routes, you use something called **[route parameters](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-parameters)**, something like this

```
Route::get('/visit/{id}', 'Controller@someMethod');
```

This id will be available as a parameter in your handler funtion,

```
public function someMethod($id) {
    // you have the id here
}
```

Comment: What if you're not on that page?

Comment: will the url in browser be `/visit/1` or `/visit/?id=1` ?

Answer (score 4):

Simple example:

```
as link=>   example.com/user/1

as rout=> Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@user');

as UserController function 

public function user($id){

    echo $id;

}

output => 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to declare the url's structure at routes including the id, for example:

```
// {{ URL::to('editpatient/'.$patient->pID) }}
Route::get('editpatient/{patientId}', 'MyController@index');
```

Then, just inject the id in the controller's function:

```
public function index($patientId){
    // $patientId is the variable from url
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the answered question for how to get a parameter from a route. But if you stumbled on this old Laravel thread looking for how to retrieve a model by its ID, the simplest way is to instantiate the model in the controller's request parameter:

```
Route::get('/retrieve_product/{product}', 'SearchController@getProduct');
```

Then over in your controller, you simply need:

```
use App\Product;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function getProduct( Product $product ) {
        return $product;
    }
}
```

That's it. No find, no where, no get, no first etc.

So, in this example, if you visit `/retrieve_product/1` the first product is returned to you.

Comment: Also, please take notes that if the data with given id doesn't exists, it will return error 404.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('post/user/{id}','ProductController@allpost')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

**Controller**

```
public function allpost($id)
    {
        $products = Product::where('uploadby', $id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(5); <br>
        return view('product.user_product')->with('products', $products);
    }
```