# Extract Id or Specific part from URL using PHP

Tags: php, laravel

i want to extract `id` from URL Like URL is `https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/49730-red-riding-hood?language=en-US`
it should be like `$id = 49730`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 getting ID from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33266316/laravel-5-getting-id-from-url)

Comment: Can you post some code around what you have tried till now?

Comment: Problem is solved you can check the answer again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
$url = 'https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/49730-red-riding-hood?language=en-US';

$urlFromBrowser = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; // or you can get the url from the browser

$id = preg_split('#([0-9]+)#', $url, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE)[1];

echo $id;

// ALTERNATIVE REGEX

$id2 = str_replace('-', '', preg_split('#([0-9]+[-]{1})#', $url, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE)[1]); // this REGEX takes in case the '-' after the number so it can be better to check with this one if the URL might contain multiple numbers at different positions

echo $id2;
```